# How to remove current bookmark in Leaflet Javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps

It happens that I have a marker on a Leaflet map which marks the point on the map well when I click on it, the problem is that if I click again it adds another marker, that is, there are two left but I only want the last one to remain visible.

this is how i add the bookmarks when i click

```
  var lat = (e.latlng.lat);
    var lng = (e.latlng.lng);

    L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(mymap)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the marker into a variable and overwrite the latlng

```
var marker;

mymap.on('click',function(e)=>{
   if(marker){
      marker.setLatLng(e.latlng);
   }else{
      marker = L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(mymap);
   }
})
```